# Question about accessing firestore subcollections in apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-firestore

I am not a strong developer but have limped along enough to connect a couple of google sheets to our firestore database to add, remove and update.

I am now trying to access nested documents (subcollections) within a document. In our case, it is a hiking application. We have "hikes" under "users". I can't find the right syntax for this.  I have the following.

```
const allUserDocuments = firestore.getDocuments("users");

for (i = 0; i < allUserDocuments.length; i++) {
  oneUserHikesDocument = allUserDocuments[i].getDocuments("hikes");
}
```

This does not work with the error

TypeError: allUserDocuments[0].getDocuments is not a function

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you're using this library to access Firestore: https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript. Can you confirm (and preferably also include that info in your question?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in the documentation of [`getDocuments`](https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript/wiki/Firestore-Method-Documentation#getdocuments), you can pass the path to the subcollection in as the first parameter. So something like this:

```
getDocuments(allUserDocuments[i].path+"/hikes");
```

Or:

```
getDocuments("users/"+allUserDocuments[i].name+"/hikes");
```